# Rspec-Running test cases on Heroku

Tags: rspec

I am new to Ruby on Rails Programming.I am using Rspec to write unit test cases.I am unable to run the test cases on Heroku. I am able to run on localhost. Can someone please give me the solution on how to run the Rspec test cases on heroku through command line?

I use the command- `heroku run bundle exec rspec --remote appname`

I get this error message

```
bundler: command not found: rspec
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`.
```

The matter is that I have already installed `rspec-rails` and `rspec gems`.
Please help me on this issue?

Comment: You don't run specs on production, specs are meant to be run on a development environment or a testing environment, not a production server.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku installs gems from production group, which is why it cannot find `rspec`. It is quite unusual to run tests on Heroku, why do you want to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku I believe has CI integration, where you can automatically run tests instead of doing it manually.

But I do I suppose you could do this manually from a testing app - and I don't really recommend doing it this way.

1. You will have to specify, in your gem file, rspec to be in your production group - as @mrzasa says.
2. Then you will have to run the command:  `heroku run rspec . remote --staging` where staging will be the name of the remote.
3. Don't forget to remove rspec from the production group, and secondly, you should not automatically "promote to production" your staging app in heroku, because that app will have rspec in its production environment.

In short I don't recommend your methods, but that's how you could probably do it if you wanted to.